Drag an image from a form into the CKEditor area
I have built myself a cms in PHP for a news website. As editor I use CKEditor. I do not use CKEditor to upload images, I have written a module for this myself.
In a table I put a reference to the uploaded images, also the text captions. On the html form where also the CKEditor Area is displayed I display the images.
Is there a possibility to drag the images into the CKEditor to add them to the text, or at least the path to the image?
